# Regular expression to match strings that do NOT contain all specified elements

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'd like to find a regular expression that matches strings that do NOT contain all the specified elements, independently of their order. For example, given the following data:

```
one two three four
one three two
one two
one three
four
```

Passing the words `two three` to the regex should match the lines `one two`, `one three` and `four`.

I know how to implement an expression that matches lines that do not contain ANY of the words, matching only line `four`:

```
^((?!two|three).)*$
```

But for the case I'm describing, I'm lost.

Comment: @JvdV it cannot hold both words at the same time, just one of them it's ok

Comment: Also, `^(?!.*\b(two|three)\b.*\b(?!\1)(two|three)\b).*` [should work](https://regex101.com/r/dAGIye/1). Extesion for three words will [look like this](https://regex101.com/r/dAGIye/2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question. It looks like you are looking for some `AND` logic. I am sure someone can come up with something better, but I thought of two ways:

```
^(?=(?!.*\btwo\b)|(?!.*\bthree\b)).*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OaLmfW/1)

Or:

```
^(?=.*\btwo\b)(?=.*\bthree\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|^.*$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OaLmfW/2)

In both cases we are using positive lookahead to mimic the `AND` logic to prevent **both** words being present in a text irrespective of their position in the full string. If just one of those words is present, the string will pass.

Answer (score 3):

Use this pattern:

`(?!.*two.*three|.*three.*two)^.*$`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0qNaYE/3)

Comment: It does not match `two four`

Comment: Thanks, I accepted @JvdV's answer because it can be applied to more than 2 words